# When a control won't be rendered, why are its properties evaluated?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Having a nested control under a `Visible=false`, why ASP.NET trying to compile it?

The [Control.Visible Property documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.visible(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> If a container control is not rendered, any controls that it contains
>   will not be rendered

My CodeBehind:

```
  public MyClass myVariable = null;
```

My view code is:

```
<asp:panel runat="server" Visible="false">
        <img id="imgNotConfirmedPhoto" src="<%# myVariable.Whatever %>" />
</asp:panel>
```

It throws an exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

when tries to compile `myVariable.Whatever`. Why is ASP.NET trying to evaluate the image `src` if the container has `Visible=false`?

Comment: try replacing  `Visible` property with  `style="display:none`

Comment: @Venky that's not the question, and won't change a thing.

Comment: @Venky, I can't replace it. The code has been simplified to have a clearer code at the question

Comment: downvoters, downvoters everywhere without any comment or suggestion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in [MSDN: ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), the entire page will be parsed and loaded long before they will be rendered.

This includes controls that won't be visible after rendering (for example when they, or their parent controls have `Visible = false`).

So whether a control will be rendered or not, it will be parsed and loaded, and its properties will be evaluated, causing the exception you see.

Comment: Thanks, @CodeCaster But, is it not a bad idea in term of performance?

Comment: @Mario the control still has to be loaded because it can be set to `Visible = true` in code, and because it can receive or raise events.